# PHP SSH Connection via exec works when called from commandline but not via apache

Tags: php, ssh, exec

My case is similar to [PHP shell_exec running a shellscript with ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123099/php-shell-exec-running-a-shellscript-with-ssh) but not the same.

Situation: I exchanged ssh-keys between the 2 servers, switched to the `www-data` user and connecting to the 2nd server via SSH works without password.

Test 1: ssh user@10.8.0.6 Documents/run.sh list
        works fine when executed in shell

Test 2: Putting a simple PHP Exec in a PHP file works fine. It returns an Array and the Retval is 0

Test 3: Putting the exec into a "big" PHP script and calling it will result in Retval 255 (Fatal Error ?!?!?)

So at the moment I don't really understand why it isn't working. I tried to figure out more details about the retval 255 but didn't get far.

The difference must be somewhere in PHP5 vs PHP5 cli. But before I had to use OpenVPN it worked fine also via normal Apache call.

Comment: Start by trying to get a more informative error by spawning SSH with `2>&1`, e.g. `$retval = shell_exec("/path/to/ssh ... 2>&1");`, so that you can inspect `$retval`. That might show you some easy fix. Otherwise I'll try with a 'diagnostic' answer.

Comment: thx for the hint, was very good: Return Host key verification failed.

so although it worked with www-data on commandline, the host verfication doesn't work here strange...

Comment: Gern geschehen :-). What was it?

Comment: i rechecked that i changed the home directory of www-data to the home folder where i created the ssh keys www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/home/www-data:/bin/sh

Comment: I found a similar problem, so in case it helps anyone else... I could ssh on the command line, but not when run from a script. The problem was I had agent forwarding turned on (in Putty) when I logged into the machine *from which* I was doing the ssh, so the problem with my certificate (which was that it I hadn't got the permissions right) was not showing up because it used my forwarded key instead. I had to turn off agent forwarding to see the error message that the script was presumably also getting but wasn't being captured in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Generic

The first level of diagnosis for `shell_exec` problems is trying to get a more informative error by spawning the same command adding 2>&1, e.g. in your case

```
$retval = shell_exec("/path/to/ssh ... 2>&1");
```

and inspecting `$retval`.

### Update

'Host key verification failed' means that the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` for the user running Apache contains a different key. Check in the file both hostname and IP keys; in a pinch, delete both, log in as user `www-data` and reinstate the keys by connecting manually.

It is also possible, if connecting with a hostname, that the IPs have changed due to DHCP or different VPN tunnels being up, and that is not the host you're looking for.

In the case of SSH, it is possible to execute it with `-vvv` very violently verbose option, and then parse through the kilobytes of output searching for the source of the `known_hosts` file. It can also be useful to `shell_exec` diagnostic commands such as

```
$ret = shell_exec('set');
```

to see the value of `HOME` variable.

Comment: ok good start, there must be a permission error on my system i created /home/www-data for the www user and chowned it to www-data:www-data but when i change to www-data "su www-data" and try and ls -all on the home directory "ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied" although permission is on 0755

Comment: APACHE_LOCK_DIR='/var/lock/apache2' APACHE_LOG_DIR='/var/log/apache2' APACHE_PID_FILE='/var/run/apache2.pid' APACHE_RUN_DIR='/var/run/apache2' APACHE_RUN_GROUP='www-data' APACHE_RUN_USER='www-data' IFS=' ' LANG='C' OPTIND='1' PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'

Comment: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

Comment: Good answer -- helped me troubleshoot my own issue with shell_exec() and SSH. Thanks!

Comment: `2>&1` was helpful.